# Python string.replace, only replace under certain circumstances

Tags: python, string, replace

I'm analyzing sales data I got from receipts. All bought items are in one column as one string like this:

```
'1 x Sandwich, "2 x Coffee, with cream", 1 x Apple pie'
```

I wish to separate all items to calculate the amount of items bought. A simple `string.split(',')` won't do, since there are also commas in the names of certain items. Luckily, these names are encapsulated by double quotes and 'normal' names are not.

**How can I replace the commas within double quotes and not the commas separating items?**

If these commas in names change into colons, for example, parsing the string can be done with `string.split()`. So the desired output will be something like this:

```
'1 x Sandwich, "2 x Coffee: with cream", 1 x Apple pie'
```

There might be other solutions, but this problem got me thinking about replacing very specific characters.

Comment: The `csv` module should be able to parse that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
text = '1 x Sandwich, "2 x Coffee, with cream", 1 x Apple pie'

def comma_changer(text):
  text = list(text)
  quote_counter = 0
  for i,char in enumerate(text):
    if char == '"':
      quote_counter+=1
    elif char == ",":
      if quote_counter%2 == 1:
        text[i] = ":"
  return("".join(text))

comma_changer(text) #'1 x Sandwich, "2 x Coffee: with cream", 1 x Apple pie'
```

Comment: This did the trick! If I understand correctly: the function separates all characters and when it finds a double quote starts changing commas to colons until it finds another. While the amount of double colons found is uneven, it means the code is still within a product name and keeps replacing commas. Is my assessment correct?

Comment: Please explain your code and show us the output.

Comment: @larwain It is still not clear what you asking for. Sorry.

Comment: @Iarwain Yep ;)

Answer (score 0):

you need to try to tell it to separate it by a specific character. in this case, try string.split('"')

Answer (score 0):

Your input is invalid because of one missing closing `"` and one missing opening `"`.

```
"1 x Sandwich, "2 x Coffee, with cream", 1 x Apple pie"
             ^                           ^
```

I am using Pythons `csv` module here. Very important is the option `skipinitialspace` because you have blank chars (space) after your `,` which is unusual in CSV files.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import io
import csv

your_invalid_input = '"1 x Sandwich, "2 x Coffee, with cream", 1 x Apple pie"'
valid_input        = '"1 x Sandwich", "2 x Coffee, with cream", "1 x Apple pie"'

# this simulates a file object
raw_data = io.StringIO(valid_input)

csv_reader = csv.reader(raw_data,
                        delimiter=',',
                        skipinitialspace=True)

for line in csv_reader:
    print(line)
```

The output is

```
['1 x Sandwich', '2 x Coffee, with cream', '1 x Apple pie']
```

Comment: I have placed the double quotes to indicate a string. When reading the CSV with Pandas, it gives me no errors in relation to this. Everything between the first and last double quote is a string in a column. 
Also, I don't want to split up amounts and item names. Ideally, the output in list form would be `['1 x Sandwich', '2 x Coffee: with cream', '1 x Apple pie']`